# How build JSON file from two tables in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables related to each other by two columns, i need to get data from table 2, for to complete array in JSON File.

**Table 1**

```
id | time | ruta |  destino  |
------------------------------
1  | 1hr  | M17  |  Town     |
2  | 24m  | M11  |  Town     |
```

**Table 2**

```
id | ref  | ruta |  destino  |
------------------------------
1  | A01  | M17  |  Town     |
2  | A08  | M17  |  Town     |
3  | A09  | M17  |  Town     |
4  | A11  | M17  |  Town     |
5  | A41  | M11  |  Town     |
6  | A15  | M11  |  Town     |
```

I need select from table 2, all data of `ref` column, related with `ruta` and same `destino`, for it show in JSON file in this order: `"ref":"A01, A08, A09, A11"`

```
[{
            "id":"1", 
            "ruta":"M17",           
            "destino":"Town",
            "ref":"A01, A08, A09, A11",
        },{
            "id":"2", 
            "ruta":"M11",           
            "destino":"Town",
            "ref":"A41, A15",
        },
```

My query is this `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1");` but i dont know like i do, i am noob in php, thnks

Comment: You could simply parse the array in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need  result from both the table you could use a join  and group_concat  with group by

```
"SELECT t1.id, t1.ruta, t1.destino, group_concat(t2.ref)  as ref
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ruta = t2.ruta and t1.destino = t2.destino 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.ruta, t1.destino "
```

Comment: Hi thnks for u help, but i have two problems, `t2.ref` show in JSON file like empty  and JSON not while with another data, only show me `ID 1` related with ruta `M17` and `ruta M11` not show

Comment: answer  updated  with alias ref for group_concat  ..  for M11 check better  .. based  on you data sample the query  must return two rows  one for M17 and one for M11

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
<?php

/*

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, ruta CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1,'M17'),
(2,'M11');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;

CREATE TABLE t2
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,ref CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,ruta CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
(1,'A01','M17'),
(2,'A08','M17'),
(3,'A09','M17'),
(4,'A11','M17'),
(5,'A41','M11'),
(6,'A15','M11');

 SELECT t1.*
      , t2.ref
   FROM t1
   JOIN t2
     ON t2.ruta = t1.ruta
  ORDER
     BY t1.id
      , t2.id;
+----+------+-----+
| id | ruta | ref |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | M17  | A01 |
|  1 | M17  | A08 |
|  1 | M17  | A09 |
|  1 | M17  | A11 |
|  2 | M11  | A41 |
|  2 | M11  | A15 |
+----+------+-----+

*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
 SELECT t1.id
      , t1.ruta
      , t2.ref
   FROM t1
   JOIN t2
     ON t2.ruta = t1.ruta
  ORDER
     BY t1.id
      , t2.id;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row;
}


$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $row){

   $new_array[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['ruta'];
   $new_array[$row['id']]['ruta'][] = $row['ref'];

}

$json = json_encode($new_array);

echo($json);


/*

Outputs: {"1":{"id":"M17","ruta":["A01","A08","A09","A11"]},"2":{"id":"M11","ruta":["A41","A15"]}}

or something like that

*/

?>
```